# connecting to a vnc in aws ec2 from windows

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, vnc, amazon-web-services

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYbwY.png)

The image above is in 4 parts

1. my amzon-linux terminal. (everything seems fine...)
2. the putty window which i used to open a tunnel
3. the vnc failing to connect
4. a chunk of output from ***-netstat a*** showing no results for any relevent ports (so ports dont seem busy)

i managed to make a vnc work the first time i followed these instructions https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/  but now it just fails to connect at the end.

i feared that previous connections may still be open in some way preventing new connections but image ***4*** shows thats not the case.

what could be causing this problem?

########### extra info

my ec2 container was made fresh as amazon-linux, then I performed "sudo yum update" and then rebooted.

then once the container was open again i did the following (whole instructions below from my ec2 container (after reboot))

1. sudo amazon-linux-extras install mate-desktop1.x
2. sudo bash -c 'echo PREFERRED=/usr/bin/mate-session > /etc/sysconfig/desktop'
3. sudo yum install tigervnc-server
4. vncpasswd
   then i entered my password
5. sudo mkdir /etc/tigervnc
6. sudo bash -c 'echo localhost > /etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-mandatory'
7. sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
8. sudo sed -i 's//ec2-user/' /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
9. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
10. sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:1
11. sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1

ps) im not getting many clues from any error messages or anything. If you have any suggestions on how to interogate this problem further then that would be helpful too

##### pps)

could it be my security groups, i think i have what i need open? (see below)

[sec_groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKFso.png)

Answer (score -1):

basically, it turned out i wasnt opening the ssh tunnel properly